# When using SolrJ can I point it at a request handler?

Tags: java, solr, handler, solrj

I have created a request handler in Solr that uses dismax and limits my query to certain fields and adds boosts for relevancy on the "title" field.

This all works fine when I go directly to Solr using an http request in a browser. However my question is whether I can use the request handler if I am accessing Solr using SolrJ?

It would be better if I could control boosts and filters and so on in the request handler rather than having to make code changes but I can't see how to specify a request handler in the API.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the class SolrQuery, there is a method [setRequestHandler](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_0_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrQuery.html#setRequestHandler-java.lang.String-) that allows you to do that. You pass the name of the request handler as defined in solrconfig.xml (probably 'dismax').

Comment: As of Solr 3.6 the `requestDispatcher` handling of the **qt param** is set to false by default. See the [solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRequestHandler#Old_handleSelect.3Dtrue_Resolution_.28qt_param.29).

Comment: In solr 4.x, it's setRequestHandler